# Como abrir uma pasta específica usando o Android usando Intent

Tags: android, intent

Meu aplicativo grava vídeos na pasta Pictures/MyCamera. Tem alguma maneira de abrir, a galeria padrão do Android, somente nessa pasta?
Usei esse código e não funcionou.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/Pictures/MyCameraApp/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "mp4/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Olá @tiago-amaral, tudo bem? Eu desejo acessar a pasta onde que meu app grava, os vídeos feito pela câmera. Que fica em Pictures/MyAppCamera. No caso eu queria abrir um intent, para o usuário poder selecionar o vídeo entendeu? Quando eu coloco o "*/*", ele mostra todos vídeos, das outras pasta. O que eu quero que ele mostre somente da minha pasta específica.

Comment: Boa tarde, não funcionou =/. Meu app ele grava vídeo em uma pasta chamado Pictures/MyCameraApp, e se eu colocar, intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*"). Ele aparece os vídeos, mas porém de todos app. Eu gostaria de aparecer somente do meu aplicativo, há possibilidade fazer isso?

Comment: @Rayanne sua pergunta nao foi clara, e onde ficaria o uso da internet? Deu a entender que vc quer acessa via internet os videos salvos em uma pasta do teu app? Ou a pasta padrão do Android para videos? Se puder reformular sua pergunta e exclarecer fica melhor para orientar.